# Reducing the width of the "tcolorbox"

Tags: equations, tcolorbox, theorems, border, box

My question is related to reducing the border margins to fit into the items inside the **tcolorbox**. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{Theorem} : $a x + by = c$
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean, line this? `\begin{tcolorbox}[width=5cm]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to fit  a one lined contents, use `\tcbox`:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbox{\textbf{Theorem} : $a x + by = c$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is simple and elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just define width of box with option `width=<desired width>`:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=55mm] % <---
\textbf{Theorem} : $a x + by = c$
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]