# How to trim (adjust) a coloured box to a text?

Tags: text, lengths, trimbox

I have a coloured box that i use, and it always takes up the whole line no matter the texts length. I would like it to stop with the text. [image]

```
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{redbox}   {colback=red!   5!white,  colframe=red!     75!black}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191131/how-to-set-fit-height-and-width-for-tcbox-according-to-the-text-inside?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539304/reducing-the-width-of-the-tcolorbox for some easy to understand examples.